# oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleBlobInputStream cannot be cast to org.springframework.core.io.InputStreamSource

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, spring-jdbc

> java.lang.ClassCastException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleBlobInputStream cannot be cast to org.springframework.core.io.InputStreamSource

```
helper.addAttachment(MyDTO.getFileName(), (InputStreamSource) MyDTO.getBlobInputStream());
```

While casting from `inputStream` to `InputStreamSource` I am getting this exception.

Comment: Some sample code will help.

Comment: Please help me. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't just cast it to `InputStreamSource`, the OracleBlobInputStream doesn't implement this interface which is Spring specific. You have to use a `org.springframework.core.io.InputStreamResource`

```
 helper.addAttachment(MyDTO.getFileName(), new InputStreamResource(MyDTO.getBlobInputStream()));
```